# I haVe C# api this api code i want use it in python can anyone help me?

Tags: c#, python-3.x

I want to use this C# API (library) in python:
https://github.com/mz-automation/libiec61850/tree/v1.4/dotnet/IEC61850forCSharp

can anyone help me ???

Answer (score 1):

There is an implementation called *Python For .Net*: https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet

You need to build the .net project first and create the library file, and then you can load it with python for .net and use its classes from there.

> Python for .NET is a package that gives Python programmers nearly seamless integration with the .NET Common Language Runtime (CLR) and provides a powerful application scripting tool for .NET developers.

> To load an assembly, use the `AddReference` function in the clr module:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Windows.Forms")
from System.Windows.Forms import Form
```

Full example from here:https://www.adrian.idv.hk/2018-08-15-pythonnet/

```
# load Python.NET
import clr

# the CLR namespaces are now recognized as Python packages
from System import String
from System.Collections import *
from System import Environment
drives = Environment.GetLogicalDrives()

# Load an assembly by "AddReference"
clr.AddReference('System.Speech')
from System.Speech.Synthesis import SpeechSynthesizer

spk = SpeechSynthesizer()
spk.Speak('Hello world!')
```

To hint where to find the assembly:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(r"C:\Folder\Subfolder\file.dll")
```

Comment: i already have .net project how to make library file can suggest me the process?

Comment: My mistake, you can get the library pre build here: https://pypi.org/project/pythonnet/ no need to build it. Don't forget to upvote/ accept useful answers

Comment: can you send me any sample example using pythonnet how can i access functions inside .cs files???

Comment: Check the updated version of the answer

Comment: I have used the following library sample code: import clr,sys
      sys.path.append(r'home/saleem/TESTING/dotnet')
     clr.AddReference('iec61850dotnet.dll')
 but i'm getting the error      clr.AddReference('iec61850dotnet.dll')
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find assembly 'iec61850dotnet.dll'.  my os is linux